# How can I convert these dataframe indexes into a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a dataframe with data of military spending for some countries from 2010-2017. I would to convert the years row of the dataframe:
[image]

into a column with the name "Year" and another one with the values corresponding to each year for each country. It should look like this dataframe (ignore name of third column, it's just an example):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
df.reset_index().melt('Country')
```